# How does while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was watching a tutorial series on PHP MySQLi this morning and I came across a bit of code that the author of the series didn't bother explain. I have seen this code before but never knew exactly how it works...

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    // set up a row for each record
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->firstname . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='records.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I know that its piecing together a table with the results of $result from a MySQL query but what I don't get is, how does the while loop function with an assignment going on inside the parameters?

I tried to echo out $row = $result->fetch_object() but it didn't display anything to the screen.

Comment: You should have use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug queries don't use echo.

Use var_dump() or print_r()

All your query is doing is looping and creating table rows populated with data from an sql table.

The

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
```

is simply generating a variable $row set to contents of 1 record (technically, with JOINs its more than 1 real "record", but I doubt your using that here), then while you loop through you are printing the values of the columns with $row->id.

Comment: So basically, the $row variable contains one row with firstname, lastname and id through the first loop? Then the next loop, if the query contains anymore rows it will assign that new row to $row variable?

Comment: I have one more question which I think is very similar to my orignal question. Say you have, if ($foo = $bar) { echo $foo; } ... Is this like saying if $bar variable isn't UNDEFINED or NULL, assign it to $foo evaluate to a truthy value and execute code within the conditional. @JaredDrake

Answer (score 7):

That is a standard fetch loop, used by most PHP database APIs to retrieve rows from the result resource.  [`mysqli_result::fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) retrieves the next row into an object of the generic type `stdClass`, having properties with the names of the columns returned by the query.  You can view its contents with `var_dump($row);`

When the result resource runs out of rows, it will return `FALSE`, causing the `while` loop to terminate. This pattern is very common in PHP -- some database APIs will provide an additional method to abstract the fetch loop away, just returning an array of results from a single function call, but that can be memory-inefficient on large datasets. It is sometimes preferable to retrieve the rows one at a time from the database when they are to be used.  When you are calling `fetch_object()` or its relatives, you are actually communicating with MySQL and requesting that it supply another row to PHP.  Simply calling `query()` doesn't actually send any rows back to PHP.

In a case like this, whether to use `fetch_object()` or `fetch_assoc()` (for an associative array) is really just a matter of style.

Comment: So, when the while loop has retrieved all rows and assigned them to the $row variable, the while loop will exit?

Comment: Don't get confused here @W3Geek. With each pass of the loop $row is overwritten with the next record until the records run out.

Comment: That is what I was thinking @JaredDrake. I also see how variable dumping works now. That will come in handy. I need to pick an answer. Both of you guys did awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Let's unpack what's happening in the line;

> while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

- The `$row = $result->fetch_object()` is actually a variable assignment. I would suspect the `$result` variable is a mysql resource that is the result of `[mysql_query][1]`
- There's a loop, indicated, by the `while`.
- Internally, `fetch_object` will iterate through the rows returned by mysql until there are no more, at which point, `fetch_object` will return `false`, thereby ending the loop.
- The reason that you got no result when you `echo`'ed `$row = $result->fetch_object()` is that, since it's a variable assignment, there is no output. To debug, you should instead try `var_dump($result);`

Answer (score 1):

PHP follows the syntax of C, whereby the result of the assignment operator is the value of the left operand. From the C standard:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the
>   left operand.  An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment, but is not an lvalue.

Think of it this way: When you do $x == 5, the result is either true or false. When you do $x + 5, the result is a $x increased by 5. The assignment operator works in an analogous way. When you do $x = 5, the result is 5 (the new value of $x). You can check this with the following:

```
$x = 0;
echo $x = 5;
echo "\n";
echo $x += 100;
```

That will show "5" and "105".

This syntax is slightly confusing since we typically only care about the side-effect of the = operator (storing something to a variable) and not its result (the value of the variable afterward). The `while($var = f()) { }` construct is fairly common though, since sometimes we need to simultaneously do an assignment and check the result. Another way to structure the loop would be to use an infinite loop: `for (;;) { $row = $result->fetch_object(); if(!$row) break; ... }` but that looks ugly.

The reason nothing shows up when you do `$row = $result->fetch_object()` is probably because all the rows have been retrieved already and fetch_object() is returning false.

Comment: while ($row = $result->fetch_object(), $row)? Now that is confusing. Is it just another way to write while ($row = $result->fetch_object())?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that PHP doesn't support the comma. That's only in C.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on how the while loop works, the fetch_object() member function returns an object for the next row in the resultset, or a falsy value if there are no more rows.

The while loop will then terminate when there are no more objects, because the

```
$row = $result->fetch_object()
```

will set $row to a falsy value, which is then evaluated by the while loop as

```
while (false)
```

which will end the while loop and not try to get members of a non-object value.